# Get filtered child from parent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, filter, relationship

I have a one to many relationship. So I can use this code to display all posts.

```
$tag = Tag::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$posts = $tag->posts;
```

It works correctly but I want to filter child to display. For example:

```
$posts = $tag::whereHas('posts', function($query){
$query->where('accept', 1)
})->get();
```

But it gets tags not posts. Any idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: The problem is here `$tag::whereHas` it should be `Tag::whereHas`

Answer (score 3):

In Post model you have to define relation to tag like this

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
}
```

and this is how you can get posts from specific tag

```
$slug = "my-slug";
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($slug){
    $query->where('slug', $slug)
})->where('accept', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

> Since all relationships also serve as query builders, you can add further constraints to which comments are retrieved by calling the comments method and continuing to chain conditions onto the query:

```
$comment = App\Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', 'foo')->first();
```

You can change your code to:

```
$posts = $tag->posts()->where('accept', 1)->get()
```

You can directly query the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$tag = Tag::where('slug', $slug)
    ->with(['posts' => function($q) {
        $q->where('accept', 1);
    }])->first();
$posts = $tag->posts;
```